# Get all Posts and Comments made by "me()"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

i am trying to retrieve all posts and comments "me()" created. But I dont find any way to do this. There only seem to be a way to retrieve the posts on the "me()"'s wall - but no way to retrieve all posts created by "me()" on the walls of other users.

The obvious way would be to use the actor_id field in the streams table, but thats not indexed, so the query wont work.

Google didn't return a solution either - even through i expected this to be a common problem ?

I already know how to retrieve all statuses and likes but posts and comments seem to be unsolvable...

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts` will return what you're looking for.
You need the `read_stream` permission to access this resource. ([documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts))

You definitely want posts of `type` `status` and `wall_post`.

Currently, there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve the same data over FQL.